# Is it bad to use + in place of ||?

Tags: javascript

Just noticed a peculiar side effect of automatic type casting in JS:

```
if (false || false) {

}
```

Is the same as:

```
if (false + false) {

}
```

And both `(false || true)` and `(false + true)` will return the same result (true).

Why doesn't the `+` see more use in this case? Is there a solid reason (besides possibly confusing code) that we shouldn't use `+` in place of `||`?

I imagine there might be a performance hit due to extra casting, but hey--we're saving a character! Yay for one micro-optimization in place of another!

Comment: I'd leave it to an optimizer to make code as character-short as possible, and write clear source code. Use of `+` is just not clear at all, and would likely confuse new developers to no end.

Comment: *"Why doesn't the + see more use in this case"* can you answer the opposite question? Why would someone use + instead of ||?

Comment: Why the down-votes, might I ask? Does this question not fit SO's format somehow?

Comment: Non-standard, confusing, etc.

Comment: Many of them are likely incorrectly voting in disagreement. Though, some may also find it not useful (or useful).

Comment: Whatever may be but I don't see any reason for the downvotes.

Comment: This only works correctly if what you have are definitely already booleans. Consider `x=10; x = x || true` vs `x=10; x = x + true`.

Comment: @KevinB Code golf comes to mind, for one thing. And... I just noticed that it worked, and was wondering why I hadn't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville the SO community has rotten over the years, and this is the result. I personally fear asking a question at all.

Comment: `x + y` isn't *the same as* `x || y` in behavior in all cases, and certainly isn't so by definition of the operators [*N.B.* I did not downvote either :)].

Comment: @lurker Would you mind elaborating on these other cases in an answer?

Comment: Also, I would disagree with those who are voting to close with the statement that this is a primarily opinion-based q/a. If there are cases where `+` and `||` behave fundamentally differently, it's not opinion. It's fact. I would recommend withdrawing your close vote, or changing it to something else if you *really hate this question*.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: FWIW, I agree -- there are objective reasons here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why doesn't the + see more use in this case?

Here are the reasons that come to mind:

1. People don't think to use it, because they're thinking logic, not math.
2. `+` will always evaluate both sides of the expression; `||` won't evaluate the right-hand operand *at all* if the left-hand operand is truthy. Doesn't matter for `if (boolean || boolean)`; can matter a lot for `if (func() || func())`.
3. `||` has this [wonderfully powerful behavior](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) that the expression's result is the value of the first truthy operand, *not* `true` or `false`, which is incredibly useful. `+` would result in a number or a string, which would be less useful.
4. `||` will test its arguments for truthiness/falsiness; `+` will either convert them to numbers or to strings, depending on what it sees on either side. So there are plenty of cases where `||` and `+` will give you different results.
5. Using `+` would require that you be pretty darned up to speed on what `+` will do with various types on either side, making code less clear and harder to maintain.
6. It's just the wrong operator (okay, so this one's pretty subjective :-) ). `||` is there for logical comparisons, why not use it?

Comment: I really like this answer. Thanks for shedding some light on the matter.

Comment: Convert to a community wiki answer? Seems like a good case for it. And it's not like you need the points ;)

Comment: @j08691: LOL true, although as I just threw out what came to my mind rather than summing up the community's reaction.

Answer (score 2):

`false || false` returns `false`

`false + false` returns `0` (which is implicitly casted to `false`)

So yes, it does kind of work, but..

`||` is the standard way of doing this, as seen in other programming languages. `+` definitely confuses people and in the end, isn't correct:

`false || true === true` is `true`

`false + true === true` is `false`

Answer (score 1):

Because `||` is an **or** operator, and serves its meaning better than `+` which is just adding `0 + 0` to result in `false`.

When using `+`, the casting is also done to `0` and `1` for `false` and `true`, and one might not know why was two booleans added, but `||` makes it obvious.

And finally

> I imagine there might be a performance hit due to extra casting, but
>   hey--we're saving a character! Yay for one micro-optimization in place
>   of another!

**Extra casting > saving a character**

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
var a=-1;
var b=false;
var c=1;
if(a)alert(true);
if(b)alert(true);
if(c)alert(true);  
//two of the above coerce to `true`
if(a+b+c)
{
  alert("phew");
}
else
{
  //yet we hit this branch
  alert("wtf");
}
```

Still a good idea?